# Converting REST API JSON schema into a CQL Cassandra schema

Tags: json, rest, cassandra, jsonschema, cql

I want download data from a Rest API into a database.The data I want save are typed objects, like java object. I have chosen cassandra because it support the type Array type, Map type, versus standard SQLdatabase(Mysql, Sqlite,..). It is better to serialize java object.

In first, I should create the tables CQL from json schema of REST API. How it is possible to generate CQL table from json schema of REST API.

I know openapi-generator can generate mysql schema from json schema, but don't support CQL for the moment. So I need to search a alternative solution.

Comment: I'm not aware of something working with openapi out of box... maybe you can look onto Stargate (https://stargate.io/)

Comment: Thank for your response. I have take a look on Stargate 's REST API 's "Create a table" section https://stargate.io/docs/stargate/1.0/quickstart/quick_start-rest.html#_create_a_table. But the json schema format used to submit the create table request is different from the swagger json schema used by REST API of the website that I want download data. So I can't automatically generate table in Cassandra using Stargate.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used off-the-shelf packages extensively to manage Cassandra schema but there are possibly open-source projects or software like Hackolade that might do it for you.

https://cassandra.link/cassandra.toolkit/ managed by Anant (I don't have any affiliation) has an extensive list of resources you might be interested in. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I will look it